# Single phase and three phase delta connection wiring diagram

Tags: transformer

I would like to verify whether my answers to the provided questions are correct for the wiring diagram I will be creating. Thank you

[image: Answer]

Edit: This is the given example to us. So is it safe to assume that connecting the two 190V would give me 380V output?

[image: Example]

Comment: It completely depends on the internal wiring inside the boxes shown in your question.

Comment: Assuming transformer windings and educational setting, both are correct.